# getInstanceTypesFromInstanceRequirements always return 0 instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-java

I am running the following API:

```
GetInstanceTypesFromInstanceRequirementsResult instanceRequirementsResult = this.amazonEC2Client
            .getInstanceTypesFromInstanceRequirements(new GetInstanceTypesFromInstanceRequirementsRequest()
                    .withInstanceRequirements(new InstanceRequirementsRequest().
                                                    withVCpuCount(new VCpuCountRangeRequest().withMin(0).withMax(100)).
                                                    withMemoryMiB(new MemoryMiBRequest().withMin(0).withMax(100))).
                                                    withArchitectureTypes(ArchitectureType.X86_64).
                                                    withVirtualizationTypes(VirtualizationType.Hvm).withMaxResults(100));
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_GetInstanceTypesFromInstanceRequirements.html), this is the minimum number of parameters that you need to pass. But this returns 0 instances. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_InstanceRequirementsRequest.html):

> MemoryMiB:
>
> The minimum and maximum amount of memory, in MiB.
>
> Type: MemoryMiBRequest object
>
> Required: Yes

The parameter MemoryMiB is expressed in MB. So with a Max of 100MB, you are not obtaining results.

Try changing it to a higher value (e.g. 4096 = 4GB) or [omitting the 'Max' field to set as unlimited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_MemoryMiBRequest.html):

> Max
>
> The maximum amount of memory, in MiB. To specify no maximum limit, omit this parameter.
>
> Type: Integer
>
> Required: No